# why i cannot login windows azure portal using my custom domain which hosted by live domain service

Tags: azure, portal, azure-connect

My Microsoft ID use my custom domain '*@jeanfish.com'. Recently when i want to login azure portal, the login page remind me that i cannot use this ID to login.
It also tell me that i will logout all microsoft services if i using my domain.
ps. My domain use Microsoft live domains service and my ID is also used for hotmail email and other microsoft services.
In my account, i have three subscriptions. And i want to use the portal to manage my hosted azure website. please help me to figure out my puzzle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please open a support request with Windows Azure Support, this will be addressed immediately.

https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?gprid=14928&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn&ln=en-us

mention you Login ID, Windows Azure Subscription ID and the error message.